Detailed Proof of Proposition 2.12 a) from Diamond, Darmon, Taylor, "Fermat's Last Theorem."
I seek a highly detailed proof of this statement in the split multiplicative reduction case. The result can be found on page 57 here.
That is, if $E/\mathbb Q$ has split multiplicative reduction at $p$ and $\ell$ is any prime, I want to prove that
$$\rho_{E,\ell}|_{I_p} = \begin{pmatrix}
\chi_\ell & * \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\rho_{E,\ell}$ is the $\ell$-adic representation attached to $E$, $\chi_\ell$ is the $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character, and $I_p$ is an inertia group at $p$.
Tate Uniformization gives us that the $\ell^\infty$-torsion extension of $E$ over $\mathbb Q_p$ is given by $\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{\ell^n}, q^{1/\ell^n})$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, where $\zeta_{\ell^n}$ is a primitive $\ell^n$th root of unity and $q \in p\mathbb Z_p$ is suitably chosen. In particular, we have an exact sequence
$$0 \to \mu_{\ell^\infty} \to E[\ell^\infty] \to A \to 0$$
where $A$ is $E[\ell^\infty]/\mu_{\ell^\infty}$. We know that $G_p$, the Galois group at $p$, acts on $\mu_{\ell^\infty}$ as $\chi_\ell$ by definition, so it suffices to show that $G_p$ acts trivially on $A$. I have written down and read a dozen or so attempts, and none of them are clear and detailed enough for me to feel comfortable.

When you state "I have written down and read a dozen or so attempts" , I can feel your agony , yet you did not list those attempts. Hence what-ever you get here is likely to repeat those attempts. It may make sense to list at least one attempt to show where your Difficulty lies.

The attempts were in private conversations with a few people, and I don't think it is appropriate to a) name drop, or b) hash out the details of each attempt here.

No worries. You wanted something "highly detailed" , though you have settled for a "short gist" , which may or may not have been among your dozen attempts

You need to show that for all $\sigma \in G_p$, all $n \ge 1$, and all $\ell^n$-th roots $Q$ of $q$ in $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p$, we have $\frac{\sigma(Q)}{Q} \in \mu_{\ell^\infty}$. But $\sigma$ is a field automorphism, and acts trivially on $\mathbf{Q}_p \ni q$, so
$$\left(\frac{\sigma(Q)}{Q}\right)^{\ell^n} = \frac{\sigma\left(Q^{\ell^n}\right)}{Q^{\ell^n}} = \frac{\sigma(q)}{q} = 1. $$
